# How to download all photos from Facebook Messenger Conversation? JavaScript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, facebook, download, console, messenger

I am having hard time downloading all photos from one conversation on Messenger.

I'm trying to do it through JS console on Chrome.
I've found that when You open the photos in lightbox, scroll through all of them(so they all load to browser), they're all in one div, that has anchors with the same className and href attribute leading to full res photo. So i thought first I'll create a table with all URLs and then figurure out how to trigger download on all of them.

that was my unsuccessful attempt:

```
var anchors = [];
document.getElementsByClassName('_42rl').forEach(function(value, index, ar) {
anchors.push(ar[index].href);
});
```

but this results in an error:

> VM883:2 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function
>       at :2:42

so i tried this:

```
var base = document.getElementsByClassName('_42rl');
var list = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(base, function(element, index, array){
    list.push(element.getElementsByTagName('a').href);
});
```

which resulted in array full of undefined values..

Comment: you know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right?

Comment: both getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName  returns an HTMLCollection. Hence, in your Array.prototype.forEach.call you need to call again  this for getElementsByTagName

Comment: to luschn: scraping? I'm trying to get around 700 photos from one conversation, not harvest terrabytes. ;) besides, it's 'my' data anyway.

@gaetanoM Could You expand your answer with example? I know that it returns HTMLCollection but I don't really know how to work on it..

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you can try Messages Saver for Facebook, a Chrome extension that can download media from a Messenger chat https://chatsaver.org/files.html

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, but thank you :)
I know, that there are plugins for that, but I strongly insist on creating my own. Last time i tried to do the task above, I was continuously crashing my browser tho.

Answer (score 1):

Because you get this error:

> document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

This happens because getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName return an HTMLCollection collection. In some browser the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is not defined. Hence you can:

1. create a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
2. use again your **Array.prototype.forEach.call** method

You may read more about HTMLCollection  on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

An example:

```js
var base = document.getElementsByClassName('_42rl');
var list = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(base, function(element, index, array){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(ele, idx) {
        list.push(ele.href);
    });
});
console.log(list);
```

```html
<div class="_42rl"><a href="11">Anchor 11</a><a href="12">Anchor 12</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="2">Anchor 2</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="3">Anchor 3</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="4">Anchor 4</a></div>
```

Using the Polyfill:

```js
// Polyfill
if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "undefined") {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

if (typeof HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach === "undefined") {
    HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

// your code....
var list = [];
document.getElementsByClassName('_42rl').forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    element.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        list.push(ele.href);
    });
});
console.log(list);
```

```html
<div class="_42rl"><a href="11">Anchor 11</a><a href="12">Anchor 12</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="2">Anchor 2</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="3">Anchor 3</a></div>
<div class="_42rl"><a href="4">Anchor 4</a></div>
```

Comment: It's a great answer, thank You. I've got my array of urls, now I have to figure out how to trigger download on all of them..